# How to add form data to a bootstrap modal in the same page by using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, bootstrap-modal

I have a requirement and trying to write code for Where user enters/selects some information in form then clicks on Submit button then a popup window(bootstrap modal) appears with just one single input box where user just types a name for that selection. What I am doing here is once user gives some information in form & after clicks on submit button I am storing that form before popup modal opens(in the middle of after user clicks on submit button and a popup window opens I am storing the given form inputs and fetching that last inserted record id and binding that id to a hidden input field in the popup modal), after popup window opens user types a name and clicks on Save button then I will be updating that record by using the same record id. The problem Am facing here is after user enters all form data and he clicks on submit button I am storing this data in the database before a popup window opens, after popup window opens in popup window if user clicks on close or Esc button without giving a name then that form data is already saved with empty name becoz user didn't give a name in popup box because as he clicks on 'close' or 'Esc' button but my requirement is if user doesn't give a name then that record shouldn't be stored in the database.

My Form code:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="my_form_id" class="my_form_class"> 
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <input type="radio" name="my_input_name_116" class="all select_option" data-id="116" value="all">
     <label for="all">All</label>
     <input type="radio" name="my_input_name_116" class="yes select_option" data-id="116" value="yes">
     <label for="yes">Yes</label>
     <input type="radio" name="my_input_name_116" class="no select_option" data-id="116" value="no" checked>
      <label for="no">No</label>
 </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rsModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" id="save_run_setup">SAVE RUN SETUP</button>
```

My bootstrap modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="rsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>-->
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Run Setup Name</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal_failure run_setup_error">
                <p><span class="add_failure_msg"></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="popup_success run_setup_success">
                <p><span class="add_success_msg"></span></p>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="" id="add_rs_modal">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control modal_user_id" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control modal_rs_row_id" id="rs_row_id" name="rs_row_id" value="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!--<label for="module-name">Run setup name</label>-->
                        <input type="text" class="form-control modal_runsetup_name" name="modal_runsetup_name" placeholder="Enter Run Setup Name" value="" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" class="add_runsetup_name" id="add_runsetup_name">Save Run Setup</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question here is how to carry the form input data along with a name which user is going to give in the popupbox, if user doesn't give a name then I will not save that previous form data? Any help would be appreciated.

Edited :

What I am doing is after user gives the input to the form "my_form_id" he clicks on 'save_run_setup' button then in ajax call I am storing this form values into a table and getting the last inserted row id and putting that row id in popup modal(which opens after this ajax call) asking user to enter a name for this form selection and updating that revious record with this 'name' given in modal popup. But If user doesn't give a any name then I already saved a record after user clicks on 'Save Run Setup' button. My requirement is I have to either append 'my_form_id' form data to bootstrap modal or modal input value to this form.

Comment: what i understand, example user click the radio button and it select yes.
And then user click save run setup it shows yes inside the input text box . Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Absolutely wrong, it is not related to radio buttons, user selects his choices and clicks on "save_run_setup" button then I will store this form and get that last inserted record id and I will put that id to a hidden input field in popup modal where user again enters a name for this 'Run Setup'(in my app terms). First while storing the form I am storing all input fields given data but with 'name' field as empty because that name user will give in popup box later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correct

*my requirement is if user doesn't give a name then that record shouldn't be stored in the database.*

with bootstrap modal close event and validate the input field you can make sure that if user does't fill the input field either modal remain open and show a message and if user fill the input field you can run an Ajax call to add the data to database or do what ever you like to do with it....

```
$('#rsModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
  var UserName = $("#modal_runsetup_name").val();
  if (UserName == '') {
    alert('Enter User Name');
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('do what ever you like to do');
  }
});
```

Note you don't need "Save Run Setup" button in modal, modal close button will take care of everything.

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ebnk811L/)

Comment: First Thanks for your reply. Please check my question once again as I updated it now.

Comment: you have a form > user fill form > you save data > you fetch last save id > load it in hidden input inside modal > you want user to fill the input in modal with name > you update the record against id > lemme know if this what you want or correct me if I miss something

Comment: Yes Correct Exactly Shehary, my problem now is what if user doesn't give any name in the modal? I am already storing the form data before user gives any name (by using popup modal). This entire form is dependent on 'name' which user will give in popup modal box. If user doesn't give any name then there is no meaning of saving that record previously.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say...so lemme guess again, you are stuck at the point where you have to load the last save id in modal so you can handle the user input data against last save id...?

Comment: This time your guess is wrong. I did that, I can handle the user input data against last save id, I am getting last save id and also updating that record with the given name, Its working fine but if user doesn't give any name in that scenario a record already getting saved with 'Run Setup Name'(my app terms) as empty which is not the right way. First form I am saving is entirelt dependent on 'name' which user will enter in popup modal.If user enters any name for that selection then only that record should be saved otherwise no need to save that form data.

Comment: and above answer does address the issue, if user will not enter name, it will not save / update anything in database and modal will remain open no matter how user will try to close it and when user enter the name you can save / update the record in database...that's what the code in answer is doing...

Comment: got it, I did that too by adding these fields to the button data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" then user should enter a name otherwise modal won't close. working fine. But before modal opens I am already storing that form data by making an ajax call like "$('save_run_setup').click()" script and fetching last id and putting that id on modal box. But this is not the right way if user gives a name then only I have to save that name along with form data instead of storing the form data before modal opens.

Comment: there are two possible options, do not store data in database instead store in jQuery global variables (global variables you can use in different calls) like you said you already run an ajax call with click event, do not run ajax call but only load the first form information in variables and use that information when user enter name, save all info in database (no need of last save id)....2nd option keep your current approach and if user doesn't enter name and leave the website, just delete the record against the save id.....

Comment: got it. I already thought of the second option like if names are empty then delete those records. after your 2 options I prefer to go with the 2nd option only. Thanks for your effort Shehary much appreciated it. You deserve my vote. Pleasure chatting to you. Thanks a lot Shehary.